# How to return the index of rows of a table in Excel as an array on separate cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I used `=ROW(Income)` where the table is with `Income` Id. I want to return the index of the rows as an array on several cells in excel but what is returning is only the index of 1 row.

[image]
[image]
I was expecting instead 10 11 12 on separate cells. I saw this done in a tutorial. What I am missing

Comment: What tutorial? Can you be more clear regarding what you've done so far.

Comment: Are you using Excel/Office 365?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Excel 365 or 2021 to achive this simply.
In earlier versions you need to select 3 cells and then use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` instead of `Enter` alone.
If you cannot predict the number of rows, you can select more rows, but formula would be more complex:

```
=IF(ROW()<=ROW(K6)+MAX(ROW(Income))-MIN(ROW(Income)),ROW(Income),"")
```

`K6` here is the address of the first cell, where your array formula begins.